# I need an alternative to server based Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

The company that I work for will soon (2Q) no longer be supporting SRS. They want everyone to use Business Objects. I  have over 100 SRS reports that I currently use. I need to find out if there is a way to run them locally on our webserver. Some of these reports need parameters to be selected and others get them passed in.

I would prefer not to have to rewrite all of those reports, however, if that is the only option so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [ReportViewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) in local mode. No SSRS install needed